# how does $location.path work?

Tags: angularjs, express

I am using `$location.path("/postuser/"+data.permalink)` to redirect to other view in client side.

In server side I am using expressJS to handle route request.

Problem here is `$location.path("/postuser/"+data.permalink)` sends the request to server to get data, but I have data exist already in client side. So just want to render other view.

In ExpressJS there is no router matching to the request  `$location.path("/postuser/"+data.permalink)`, because I have already have data.

**AngularRouter**

```
test.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/welcome', {templateUrl: 'partials/welcome.html', controller: 'welcomeController'});

    $routeProvider.when('/postuser/:permalink', {templateUrl: 'partials/userspostpage.html', controller: 'CrudController'});

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);


test.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Controller

```
test.controller('CrudController',function($scope,TestServ,$location){

  $scope.create = function(){


    var postData = {
        'subject' : this.title,
        'body' : this.description,
         'tags' : ""
      };


    TestServ.create(postData).success(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $location.path("/postuser/"+data.permalink)

    }).error(function(errdata){
      console.log("error"+errdata);

    })

  },


});
```

**ExpressJS router**

```
app.get("/test/:permalink", data1);
app.post('/test', data2);
app.get("/not_found", data3);
```

Please let me know how can I change the view  or render requried html.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you're running into, and correct me if I'm wrong, is that you are using routes on both angular and express. Not thats impossible or wrong, but it can lead to some confusion. Specifically with `html5Mode` turned on.

`html5Mode` uses a technology called `pushState` that will dynamically update the location bar with a given url, but not necessarily take you there. Thats what `$location` does. It updates the url and then triggers the **angular** view to change.

If you hit the refresh button after this happens you will likely get a 404. This happens because the server (express) doesn't know that angular has created its own view there.

The simplest fix is to tell express that there is a page there and have it internally rewrite that request to your main angular page.

For Example (in express):

```
app.get("/", dataN);
app.get("/welcome", dataN);
app.get("/postuser/:permalink", dataN);
```

to match whats in your angular routes.

Comment: when $location updates the ulr and triggers the angular view change, it should call corresponding view  controller first  right? But here it is not happening. Request goes to first express first !

Comment: Yes, but the controller has to be loaded into the current module. You appear to be using two modules 'test' and 'blogApp'. Is your 'test' module including the 'blogApp' module?

Comment: No, I am using only one app that is testApp.  Let me edit quest. Also I have tried your suggestion by adding same route in both anaular and express. But here express route called and once response back, again one more request like is called http://test.com/partials/userspostpage.html. Which agave 404

Comment: I think it is issue with dynamic routing. any idea